# Extending a middy middleware function in nodejs

Tags: node.js, middleware, middy

In my lambda code written in nodejs, I want to extend the `httpErrorhandler` middleware and create a wrapper around it.

Currently I have something like below.

```
module.exports.handler=middy(handle).use(httpErrorHandler(LoggingFactory.getLogger().log))
```

I want to create a `customHttpErrorHandler` which is nothing but just a wrapper outside `httpErrorHandler`.

```
module.exports.handler=middy(handle).use(customHttpErrorHandler(LoggingFactory.getLogger().log))
```

Is this possible? What do I need to put inside customHttpErrorHandler ? There is no additional functionality to be implemented. This new `customHandler` should just pass the control to standard
`httpErrorHandler`.

`customHttpErrorHandler` might look something like below (pseudo code).

```
connectHttpErrorHandler = (logger) => httpErrorHandler(logger)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi core maintainer of Middy here. Your pseudo code is almost correct. In Middy >=2.0.0, `httpErrorHandler` takes an options object. See https://github.com/middyjs/middy/tree/main/packages/http-error-handler for documentation.

```js
const connectHttpErrorHandler = (logger) => httpErrorHandler({logger})

const logger = LoggingFactory.getLogger().log

module.exports.handler = middy(handler)
  .use(customHttpErrorHandler(logger))
```